# Reuse old post ID for new post after deleting post

Tags: posts, id

I want to `Reuse` old post ID for new post after deleting some post. I have a site that has `Q&A` and I displayed the post ID before the title of each question so that the user / I can guess how many questions there are. But, new post ID is generated for a new post after published. I need to `reuse` old post ID(deleted post ID) for new post. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: You can't. That's not how IDs work in WordPress (or MySQL, which creates the IDs). I strongly suggest finding a different solution to your actual problem. You should post a question about your original problem with displaying a number to show how many questions there are.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie- Thanks.